# Having difficulty with WHERE clause in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have written a query that is supposed to display all volunteers with first aid on an event here is the code;

```
SELECT * 
FROM EventVolunteer AS ev
INNER JOIN Event AS e
ON ev.EventID = e.EventID
Inner Join Volunteer AS v 
ON ev.VolunteerID= v.VolunteerID
WHERE v.First_Aid = ‘yes’;
```

The code runs fine til the last line
WHERE v.First_Aid = ‘yes’;

I keep getting an error message that says

"Unknown column ''yes'' in 'where clause' and this table has been populated and there are some fields that contain 'yes'. Can anyone tell me why  Im getting this error message! thank you.

Comment: You need regular single quotes... those look like curly/smart quotes. Try just 'yes' instead of what you have.

Comment: Is it MySql or Sql-Server? Please tag it accordingly

Comment: Use straight single quotes.

Comment: "mysql" and "sql-server" are two completely different DBMSs.  Which one is your question actually about?

Comment: the copy/paste for the query resulted in '' being changed to the wrong quotes.  correct that and you'll be fine.

Comment: @pmbAustin Since you was the first to comment, you should add it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you guys , that resolved it thanks everyone

Comment: Done, Jorge. For what it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying from the comments:

You need regular single quotes... those look like curly/smart quotes. Try just 'yes' instead of what you have.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your single quotes are unformatted. So instead of

```
WHERE v.First_Aid = ‘yes’
```

use

```
WHERE v.First_Aid = 'yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct single quotes? In your code, I can see

> ‘yes’

Instead of

> 'yes'

Comment: I am now using them an it works perfectly  thank you !